# Image Cube Animation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the jQuery plugin Image Cube (http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html) for the first time.  I love the plugin, but within the context of my landing page I can't for the life of me get it to work.

Here's a test on my server that works well:

http://209.236.69.153/~dentalaw/test.php

And here is my landing page, which does not work (the first dentist image is what is supposed to rotate):

http://209.236.69.153/~dentalaw/

Any suggestions?  I've tried adjusting things like position, tried removing the overflow:auto.  I mean, I've really tried everything I can think of, and I can't get it to work.  Now, I turn to your greater knowledge!  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This plugin doesn't like classes, so if I just switch everything to inline styling it works like a charm!